# C callback and std::function::target

Tags: c++

I have to use a C library to grab images and it has a stream functionnality. So when calling the `start_stream` method I have to pass a function pointer. I want to pass a method from a class to that `start_stream` function.

Here is the signature of the callback method: `void StreamCallback( SomeType* img )`
and I have to pass a `void(* StreamCallbackPtr)( SomeType* img )` to the `start_stream` method which signature is `int start_stream( StreamCallbackPtr stream_callback )`

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    void Callback( SomeType* img )
    {
        std::cout << "grabbed" << std::endl;
        // Do something with the image ...
    }

public:
    void StartStream()
    {
        std::function<void( SomeType* img )> cb =
            std::bind( &MyClass::Callback, this, std::placeholders::_1 );

        if( not cb ) // if the call-wrapper has wrapped a callable object
        {
            std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
            exit(0);
        }

        ptr_fun_ = cb.target<FuncType*>();

        if( ptr_fun_ != nullptr )
        {
            start_stream( ptr_fun_ );
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
            exit(0);
        }
    }

private:
    typedef void FuncType( SomeType* img );
    FuncType* ptr_fun_;
};
```

But unfortunately `ptr_fun_` is always null. Can you spot the error ?

Comment: the code doesn't support your goal of passing a C function. for best guidance on this, please do provide the complete signature of the `start_stream` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can use a static `extern "C"` function. With most platforms you can also use a `static` member function, but formally it needs not be compatible with C, and can't be declared `extern "C"`. I think it was on Solaris that one had to disable an associated warning.
- You can not use a `std::function`, because it's not a C function: it's a C++ object with an `operator()` member function, a functor. Similarly for the result of `bind` and for a lambda that captures anything (in particular, a lmbda that captures a `this` pointer).
- Platform-specific functionality can be used to implement dynamically created C functions, but that would be like shooting a gnat (singular) with intercontinental H-bomb missiles.

So in short, go for the static `extern "C"` function.

It can use a static variable to forward to a member function on some object, if you want that. In the case where the callback receives a data pointer argument supplied by the client code you can use that as a `this`-pointer. However, given the signature `int start_stream( StreamCallbackPtr stream_callback)`  you'll just have to use some static variable, if you want to forward to an object's member function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  static variable is what I am using already. And the big constraint is that if I want multiple instances of `MyClass`, I have to add a static variables that redirects the image from the different streams. I was told that the solution I wrote in the question would work, but I had to be certain it would not.